# elastic search gives error from doc example

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am trying to learn `elasticsearch` module in python,(`pip3 install elasticsearch`) I tried to follow their doc on [Python Elasticsearch](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/), here is the code from their site:

```
from datetime import datetime
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch()

doc = {
    'author': 'kimchy',
    'text': 'Elasticsearch: cool. bonsai cool.',
    'timestamp': datetime.now(),
}
res = es.index(index="test-index", doc_type='tweet', id=1, body=doc)
print(res['result'])
```

I get this error `ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused`,is the module deprecated?

Comment: That doesn't look like a code error. It's clearly a connection error. Are you _running_ [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch)?

Comment: @Chris I installed it from "https://www.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch" not in docker also I use centOS

Comment: What do Docker and CentOS have to do with anything? You don't just have to install it. Again, _are you **running** Elasticsearch_? Can you connect to it?

Comment: @Chris if i open local-host it does give some data (name,number,build_hash...)

Comment: And is your code running on the same host as Elasticsearch? Are you running Elasticsearch on its default port?

Comment: @Chris i didn't modify anything i just followed their steps 1 by 1, i did get this warning when installing `OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.`

Comment: _Again, **is your code running on the same host as Elasticsearch?**_

Comment: @Chris Yes it is

Comment: So when you say "if i open local-host it does give some data (name,number,build_hash...)", that's on `http://localhost:9200`?